# Understanding s-domain poles, negative frequencies and bode plots

Tags: analog, signal, frequency, bode-plot

The transfer function of a low-pass filter, \$H(s)=\frac{1}{s+1}\$ has a pole at \$s=-1\$. Setting the real part of s to 0, we have a pole at \$jw=-1\$. In the bode plot of this transfer function, at \$\omega=1\$ the gain has dropped to -3db.

What I don't understand is why the effect of the pole \$jw=-1\$ appears on the bode plot at \$\omega=1\$.

I guess I am confused about the significance and relationship between the s-domain, the jw axis, and real frequencies, and how a pole in the s-domain affects the other domains.

Comment: With s=(sigma+jw)=-1 we have sigma=-1 (and NOT jw=-1).

Comment: Setting \$s\rightarrow j\omega \$ means that we are ignoring the exponential transients, \$e^{-\alpha t}\$, leaving only the steady state sinusoidal terms, \$e^{j\omega t}\$

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I am confused about the significance and relationship between
>   the s-domain, the jw axis, and real frequencies, and how a pole in the
>   s-domain affects the other domains.

This might help: -

[image]

The three pictures along the top show a 2nd order low pass filter magnitude response i.e. amplitude versus frequency. This is more conventionally called the bode plot and is the sort of thing you would see on a spectrum analyser.

Bottom left takes the bode plot into a 3D image - as you can see, behind the bode plot there is the \$\sigma\$ axis and there is a pole drawn the corresponds with the values shown.

The bottom right picture is the plan view of the 3D picture and is the standard view of the pole zero diagram.

> The transfer function of a low-pass filter, has a pole at s=−1.
>   Setting the real part of s to 0, we have a pole at jw=−1.

No, you have a pole at co-ordinates \$\sigma\$ = -1, jw = 0.

Answer (score 0):

The Laplace transform evaluated along the jw-axis gives the frequency response of the system. The "real" frequencies are therefore mapped onto the imaginary axis!

For a low-pass transfer function the corner-frequency is defined as the frequency where the absolute value of the transfer function drops by 3dB which is equivalent to a reduction by the factor of \$1/\sqrt{2}\$.

The transfer function is given by
$$
  H(s) = \frac{1}{s+1}
$$
Now the question is for which \$\omega\$ is |H(s)| reduced by  \$1/\sqrt{2}\$ which is answered by looking at the denominator and solving
$$
  \sqrt{2} = |j\omega + 1| = \sqrt{\omega^2 + 1}
$$
which results in \$\omega = 1\$.

Comment: \$\omega = -1\$ also solves this equation